# How to create multiple objects of same class , with different values , in Spring using xml config file?

Tags: spring

**appContextXmlAutowiring.xml**

```
<bean id="emp" class="com.org.epam.Assignment.Spring.XmlAutowiring.Employee" >
        <property name="name" value ="Vineet"/>
        <property name="id" value ="100"/>
        <property name="age" value ="28"/>
        <property name="addressNew" ref="addressNew"/> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="emp1" class="com.org.epam.Assignment.Spring.XmlAutowiring.Employee">
        <property name="name" value ="Ashutosh"/>
        <property name="id" value ="200"/>
        <property name="age" value ="29"/>
        <property name="addressNew" ref="addressNew1"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="addressNew1" class="com.org.epam.Assignment.Spring.XmlAutowiring.Address" >
        <property name="country" value ="India1"/>
        <property name="state" value ="Maharashtra"/>
        <property name="city" value ="Pune"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="addressNew" class="com.org.epam.Assignment.Spring.XmlAutowiring.Address" >
        <property name="country" value ="Ind"/>
        <property name="state" value ="Mah"/>
        <property name="city" value ="Punite"/>
    </bean>

    </beans>
```

**Driver Main Class**

```
public class DriverClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try{
            ApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("appContextXmlAutowiring.xml");
            Employee e = ac.getBean(Employee.class);
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            //System.out.println(e.getAddressNew().getCity());
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**Error Message**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.org.epam.Assignment.Spring.XmlAutowiring.Employee' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: emp,emp1
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1041)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:345)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:340)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1092)
    at com.org.epam.Assignment.Spring.XmlAutowiring.DriverClass.main(DriverClass.java:12)
```

> I am getting mentioned error when trying to create two different objects of same type i.e. Employee using Spring Application context.
>   Could anyone please help me in solving this error.
>
> Also please mention how to create multiple objects of same class , with different values , in Spring using xml config file ?

Thanks

Comment: did you try to add `name` attribute with different values ?? `<bean name="emp1" id="emp1" class="com.org.epam.Assignment.Spring.XmlAutowiring.Employee">`

Comment: Yes Its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two beans with the same class and then retrieve the bean by class. The error says it doesn't know which bean to choose.

You should use the

```
applicationContext.getBean(name)
```

method instead

Answer (score 0):

Your code is already creating multiple beans of same class as you defined in your xml config. That is not where the code is failing it is failing while retrieving the `Employee` bean from the application context. The reason behind this failure is pretty clear in the error message;

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'com.org.epam.Assignment.Spring.XmlAutowiring.Employee' available:
>   **expected single matching bean but found 2: emp,emp1**

You need to retrieve the bean by its name in such situation as below;

```
Employee e = (Employee) ac.getBean("emp");

Employee e1 = (Employee) ac.getBean("emp1");
```

Comment: Yes Thanks. Its working. Also got to know many overloaded methods of getBean() method. e.g. 1. Map<String, Employee> e = ac.getBeansOfType(Employee.class);